# Smarter vs Smartest when referring to twins?

Tags: phrases, superlatives

In the case of "Spencer was the smartest of the twins" is it appropriate to write smartest or would it be better to use smarter instead as there are only two.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  There are only two, so "smarter" is preferred.

> Jim was always the **bolder** of the pair.
>
> Ralph is **taller** than his brother, but also **hairier**.

Comment: "preferred" makes it sound like there's no hard rule. So "smartest" would also be semantically correct?